# How can I get rid of this error warning when using the prepareMplusData function?

Tags: r

I can't figure out a way to get rid of this error in my R script.

I prepared Data in R and then wanted to use the *prepareMplusData* function, which works well until I standardize a variable.

```r
setwd (...)
install.packages("merTools")
library(merTools)
data(hsb)

install.packges("MplusAutomation")
library(MplusAutomation)

prepareMplusData(hsb, "Mydata.dat") #it works now!
hsb$mathach <- scale(hsb$mathach) 
prepareMplusData(hsb, "Mydata_scales.dat") #now I get the error term
```

As soon as I scale my Data and try to use the prepareMplusData function, I get the following error:

```r
Error in vapply(df, class, FUN.VALUE = NA_character_) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[110]]) result is length 2
```

What can I do now? I never explicitly wrote the vapply code, so I assume, this is part of another function. How do I standardize my Data in a way, that I can export my Data to an Mplus format?

**I found out how to fix it. just needed to specify the standardized variable to a numeric**

Comment: `*` and `**` are for emphasizing *text*, not for code. `\`` (inline) and `\`\`\`` (block) is used for *code*, and while it seems mostly stylistic and/or aeshetic, it can change the readability of the question significantly. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: `scale` calls `apply` which calls `vapply`, that's a possible chain of function calls that leads to your error. Please consider making this question reproducible, there's very little we can do without sample data.

Comment: sorry, Im pretty new here. How do I make this reproducible?
Thank you for that information! Is there a different way to scale data without calling vapply?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for some good discussions on making good reproducible questions. Thanks!

Comment: Please can you heed my advice? If we naively try this code as-is, we'll first get `object 'a' not found`, then the same with `'b'`, and then I don't know what we'll get from `c(a,b,c)`, since we don't know what the first two are, and the third *might* be a `function` or it might be something else.. So *please* pay attention to [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225905/how-can-i-get-rid-of-this-error-warning-when-using-the-preparemplusdata-function?noredirect=1#comment120580494_68225905), read the links, then improve your question to make it reproducible.

Comment: I hope it works now! Sorry! I used the hsb Data, which I think is available for everyone, right?